# Grab triangles within a lower triangle

Tags: r

I have the need to grab all the three element triangles that make up the lower triangle of a symmetric matrix.  I can not think of how to grab all these pieces in the order of far left column working down and then next column to the right and so on.  I know that the numbe rof mini triangles inside of the lower triangle is:

```
n = x(x - 1)/2
where: x = nrow(mats[[i]])
```

Here I've created three matrices with letters (it's easier for me to conceptualize this way) and the elements in the order I'm looking for:

```
FUN <- function(n) {
    matrix(LETTERS[1:(n*n)], n)
}

mats <- lapply(3:5, FUN)
```

So this is the output I'd like to get (I put it in code rather than output format) for each of the matrices created above:

```
list(c("B", "C", "F"))

list(c("B", "C", "G"), c("C", "D", "H"), c("G", "H", "L"))

list(c("B", "C", "H"), c("C", "D", "I"), c("D", "E", "J"), 
    c("H", "I", "N"), c("I", "J", "O"), c("N", "O", "T"))
```

How can I do this task in the fastest manner possible while staying in base R?

Not sure if this visual of what I'm after is helpful but it may be:

[image]

Comment: Is a 5x5 matrix the largest that you would expect to have to test?

Comment: No it could be larger (though I highly doubt it would ever be much larger).

Comment: @TylerRinker - I just had to force close my R session while attempting some benchmarking on a 10K * 10K matrix. 1K*1K was a matter of a couple of seconds. I wonder if people out there might have more efficient implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice problem! Here is how you can solve it using a bit of recursion (followed by a MUCH simpler version)

```
triangle <- function(base.idx, mat) {
    upper.idx <- base.idx - 1L
    right.idx <- base.idx + nrow(mat)
    paste(mat[c(upper.idx, base.idx, right.idx)], collapse = " ")
}

get.triangles <- function(mat) {
    N <- nrow(mat)
    if (N == 3L) {
        return(triangle(3L, mat))
    } else {
        left.idx  <- 3:N
        right.mat <- mat[2:N, 2:N]
        left.triangles  <- sapply(left.idx, triangle, mat)
        right.triangles <- Recall(right.mat) 
        return(c(left.triangles, right.triangles))
    }
}

x <- lapply(mats, get.triangles)

# [[1]]
# [1] "B C F"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "B C G" "C D H" "G H L"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "B C H" "C D I" "D E J" "H I N" "I J O" "N O T"
```

I'll just comment on the output not being exactly as you asked. It is because creating recursive functions that return a flat list are always difficult to work with: somehow you always end up with nested lists...

So the last step should be:

```
lapply(x, strsplit, split = " ")
```

and it will be in the same format you asked for.

---

And here is an even simpler version (forget about recursion!)

```
get.triangles <- function(mat) {
    base.idx  <- seq_along(mat)[row(mat) > col(mat) + 1]
    upper.idx <- base.idx - 1L
    right.idx <- base.idx + nrow(mat)

    lapply(mapply(c, upper.idx, base.idx, right.idx, SIMPLIFY = FALSE),
           function(i)mat[i])
}
```

Comment: thank you that works very nicely.  I will utilize the method without recursion as there's no need to use `strsplit` (and if it's a numeric matrix no need to use `as.numeric`). +1

Answer (score 3):

Edited to add a `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` which now gives exactly what you want:

Basically, this method gets the indexes of all the top left corners of the triangles that you want and then grabs the [cell below] + [cell below + to the right]. Thrill. One added benefit of this method is that it works for `matrix` and `data.frame` objects.

```
bot.tris <- function(data) {
  idx1 <- unlist(sapply((nrow(data)-2):1,function(x) tail(2:(nrow(data)-1),x)))
  idx2 <- rep(1:(nrow(data)-2),(nrow(data)-2):1)
  mapply(function(x,y) {c(data[x,y],data[x+1,y],data[x+1,y+1])},idx1,idx2,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
}
```

And the result:

```
> result <- lapply(mats,bot.tris)
> str(result)
List of 3
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "B" "C" "F"
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "B" "C" "G"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "C" "D" "H"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "G" "H" "L"
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "B" "C" "H"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "C" "D" "I"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "D" "E" "J"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "H" "I" "N"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "I" "J" "O"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "N" "O" "T"
```

Comment: This approach is definitely less coding and very easy to understand.  I benchmarked both responses and flodel's is faster.  Both functions here are faster than what I had (nothing).  Thank you for much for tackling the problem.  +1

Comment: *"Both functions here are faster than what I had (nothing)"* - I like that :-)